# "Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at" error while assigning hash to an hash in perl

Tags: html, xml, perl

I'm assigning an hash `%attributes` to another hash `%attributes_r`. I need to print it as key/value pair of that hash `%attributes`, as mentioned below. But, while printing, why do I get this error, "Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at"  in this line "foreach my $key1 (keys %{$attributes_r{$key}})    {" ?

**My Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
our %attributes_r;
my %attributes = ('clear'      => 0,
               'reset'      => 0,
               'bold'       => 1,
               'dark'       => 2,
               'underscore' => 4,
               'blink'      => 5,
               'reverse'    => 7,
               'concealed'  => 8
               );


for (keys %attributes) {
    $attributes_r{$attributes{$_}} = $attributes{$_};
    # print "$_ => $attributes_r{$attributes{$_}}\n";
}


foreach my $key (keys %attributes_r)    {
    foreach my $key1 (keys %{$attributes_r{$key}})    {
        print "$key1 = > $attributes_r{$key}{$key1}\n";
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$_` is the key, so `$attributes_r{$attributes{$_}} = $attributes{$_};` should be `$attributes_r{$_} = $attributes{$_};`. Perhaps you should have given the loop var a name to avoid confusion... /// The second loop makes no sense.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what you want the new `$attributes_r` to look like?  I mean, show that as exactly as you can -- ideally you'd show us what  that hash should be.

Answer (score 2):

With your data, this is incorrect:

```
    foreach my $key1 (keys %{$attributes_r{$key}})  {
```

You are trying to dereference a value that is a string, not a reference, like the error says. If you did have a hash of hash, it might work, but you do not.

You might be trying to create a hash of hash, I'm not sure. This piece of code is very odd:

```
$attributes_r{$attributes{$_}} = $attributes{$_};
```

Here you are taking the value from the original hash and use it as a key in the other hash. For example:

```
$attributes_r{0} = 0;
```

This is not really going to accomplish anything useful. If you clarify what it is you are trying to do I might be able to suggest a fix.

Also, if you are trying to view the data structure you are creating, I suggest you print it with `Data::Dumper` like this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
...
print Dumper \%attributes_r;
```

Comment: I want to assign the key/value pair of %attributes hash to %attributes_r hash

Comment: How to take key/value of this %attributes hash  to %attributes_r hash in  "  $attributes_r{0} = 0; "

Comment: If you want to copy the hash, just copy the hash: `%attributes_r = %attributes`. Or loop over the key/values: `for my $key (keys %a) { $a_r{$key} = $a{$key} }`. Note that this is only for simple structures.

Comment: I don't want to take a copy of it. I want to assign this hash as a key to another hash. (ie) something like this:  $a_r{$a}{$key}

Comment: Well, you can store a hash inside another hash value, just do `$a_r{"whatever"} = \%a`.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to study the Perl documentation about data structures, and then come back with a new question.